# Using JQuery to slide down to internal link destinations?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have some internal links on my website, and I am new to JQuery. I was wondering if this there is a way for a user to click on an internal anchored link text and for the page to smoothly 'slide down' to the internal link destination?

```
    <li>apples</li>
    <li><a href="#benefits">Benefits of Joining</a></li>
    <li>peaches</li>
    ...

    ...

    ...

    ...

    ...

    <a name="benefits">Users of this site get the best benefits</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('[name="' + $(this).attr('href').substr(1) + '"]').offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
});​
```

See fiddle for example: http://jsfiddle.net/EdmxK/

You can probably find some jQuery scrolling plugins on the web, if that's what you prefer.